# Cannot connect to Heroku CLI

Tags: amazon-web-services, macos, heroku, heroku-cli

I installed heroku cli 4 months ago and used it fine. However today I wanted to login again.. however I keep getting errors.

```
zsh: command not found: heroku
```

Then I searched up online and even tried to run "brew" commands and even though I do have that in my path for "source ~/.bash_profile", it still gives me when I run "brew":

```
/bin/bash: /usr/local/Library/Homebrew/brew.sh: No such file or directory
```

this is in my path:

```
# Ensure user-istalled binaries take precedence
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH
# Load .bashrc if it exists
test -f ~/.bashrc && source ~/.bashrc
export PATH=$PATH:~/Desktop/bin
export PATH=/Library/PostgreSQL/13/bin:$PATH
export PATH=/usr/local/Homebrew/bin:$PATH
export PATH=/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/latest/bin:$PATH
export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-10.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/apt
```

I am stuck on this and cannot seem to figure out the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem.. by deleting/removing ALL HEROKU related files in my mac.
Then I ran the following commands:

```
curl https://cli-assets.heroku.com/install.sh | sh
```

which I got access from https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-cli#uninstalling-the-legacy-heroku-gem "other installation methods" without using brew, and it worked.